# In what directory do I create virtual server directory in nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/nginx-virtual-host/) to use my domain name with my home server. At this point, I enter my IP address and I can see the webpage but I want to be able to use my domain name.

I have a simple question more about Linux than nginx, I guess: In the tutorial he creates a new directory `/var/www` to keep the site files. Where is this file located? Do I create it in `/etc/nginx` directory?

---

**Edit**

I see that there is `var` directory in `/` but I don't see a `www` file in it. So should I create `www` in that `/var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real correct answer to this, some people use `/var/www` and some linux distros use `/srv` for me I prefer putting it inside `/home/[user]/www`. as long as you write the correct configuration.

check the configuration inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` at the end of the file it would include a folder which is supposed to be the configuration folder for the virtual hosts, depending on your distro it would either be `/etc/nginx/conf.d` only or with `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. create a new file and set the `root` according to what folder you choose.

You'll find that nginx by default uses `/usr/share/nginx/html`

---

**EDIT**: Adding more info according to your comment questions

1- **what is `root`**: well inside the nginx config there's a directive called `root` which tells nginx what folder to look into when a user visits a URL like `http://example.com/home.html`

Here's the [wiki page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) and here's a sample virtual server for the example I mentioned.

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.exmaple.com;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/example; # this is the root i meant
  location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
}
```

This example will look for `home.html` inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/example/`

2- **Is it good to use `/usr/share/nginx/html`**: well it's ok doesn't really matter like I said, but since you're going to create a new virtual server anyways might as well dedicate a folder for `www`. the only qustion here whether it is good practice to use linux's `/usr` it self, [check the directory structure table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure), you'll find in the table that a linux structure `/var` it self is more logical

Comment: Ok, thanks. So is it a good idea to `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory and create `www` in that directory?

Comment: And can you explain what you mean by "create a new file and set the `root` according to what folder you choose."? What does it mean to "set the root"?

Comment: @Zeynel check the answer changes

Answer (score 1):

thsi is a good example.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

if it's not there, you can create it. (/var/www/) , make sure you give correct permissions.